# Script to find functions in a C program

Tags: linux, c

I am trying to find solution to this following problem:

Given the directory structure:

```
project/
bridge/
    mysql_bridge.c
    postgres_bridge.c
```

My code should retrieve all functions in .c files from root folder and all the c programs in its subdirectories*:

- mysql_bridge.c
- postgres_bridge.c

My script should output "Unable to find any source files" if no source files were encountered.
Specifically, the only source files that should be search for are .c files (headers are ignored)

I want to use a command line argument as the root of the project. Following are the scenarios:

**Example 1:**

```
./findfn.sh project_1
project_1/ever/jump.c:
void logical_jump(int loc)
int ngoto()

project_1/indent/handle.c:
FILE* figure_out_this(char* name)
void kill_all()

project_1/mac.c:
void some(void)
int super_function(int xx, int ya)

project_1/test.c:
void this_function()
```

**Example 2:** Bad directory

```
./findfn.sh file
file is not a directory
```

**Example 3:** Unable to find functions

```
./findfn.sh project_2
Unable to find any functions
```

Comment: Look into `ctags`. It will generate a file with locations of all C functions (and possibly even variables, macros and type definitions) in a C project. It's usually used to help navigate C projects with Vim. Also, `etags` for the same thing for Emacs.

Comment: Have you considered using a tags file, an editor plugin for C development, or an IDE?  Edit: beaten by four seconds.  :)  Yes, look into `ctags`.

Comment: Yes I tried out that as well. But no luck. I am very new to UNIX and its a submission for University. No idea about this.

Comment: And which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Kusalananda That's what you'd use in the real world, but I doubt that Gb's professor would accept `ctags` as the homework submission.

Answer (score 5):

A C source file is difficult to parse, just like other structured data files. It's better to use a parser that knows about the language's syntax than to try to handle it oneself.

Assuming you have [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) installed as `ectags`:

```
find top-dir -type f -name '*.[ch]' -exec ectags -x --c-kinds=f {} ';' >table
```

This will find all `.c` and `.h` files in or under `top-dir` and create the file `table`.  The contents of `table` will look something like (with `top-dir` being `.` in this example)

```
GetTimeSeed      function    373 ./src/bayes.c    void GetTimeSeed (void)
InitializeMrBayes function    443 ./src/bayes.c    int InitializeMrBayes (void)
PrintHeader      function    821 ./src/bayes.c    void PrintHeader (void)
ReinitializeMrBayes function    838 ./src/bayes.c    int ReinitializeMrBayes (void)
main             function    101 ./src/bayes.c    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
readline_completion function    359 ./src/bayes.c    char **readline_completion (const char *text, int start, int stop)
```

(etc.)

This output format should easily be parsed with e.g. `awk` to get exactly the format you want.

Comment: Does it work in bash shell?

Comment: @K.Sopheak This is more or less independent on what shell you are using (as it's not using any particular feature of any shell). Yes, it would work in the `bash` shell.

Comment: Not gonna work with functions whose declaration spans more than a single line. Because tags file only contain the first line of a declaration, so you won't know what are the rest of arguments there.